# Solving minimization subject to constraints for matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, scipy

I have a matrix "minimize", where I want to minimize column 1 subject to the constraint that the sum of column 2 must equal 0. The second constraint is that the rows must only be summed in if the second column is not equal to zero. How do I minimize the first column of matrix "minimize", subject to the constraint that the second column for corresponding row values must equal zero?

```
minimize = np.array([[-10,  0]
                     [-7,  -1]
                     [-5,   1]
                     [-3,   0]
                     [ 0,   1])
```

I am minimizing the first column of the matrix "minimize", subject to the constraint that the second column must equal 0. Thus, the optimal solution should be equal to -12 as (-7 + -5 = -12, for the second column equaling the constraint -1 + 1 = 0).

```
def objective_function(x):
    column_sum = 0
    for row in x:
        column_sum += sum(x[0])
    return column_sum  

def con(x):
    sum = 0
    for row in x:
        sum += sum(x[1])
    return sum

def con1(x):
    sum1 = 0
    for row in x:
        sum1 += 1 - sum(x[1])
    return sum1
```

Where "cons" is equal to the constraints:

```
cons = (
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': con}
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': con1}
)

x0 = [-10]

scipy.optimize.minimize(objective_function, x0, constraints=cons)
```

Comment: What do you mean "minimize the first column"? Given two different possible sequences of numbers for the first column, how do you determine which is "minimum"? Also, how do you determine the values in the two columns?

Comment: Additionally, what is your question?

Comment: "Minimize the first column" as the most negative sum of values for the first column of the matrix, subject to the constraint that the second column equals 0. The values in the two columns are arbitrary, where the first column is integers of any value and the second is integers of values -1, 0, 1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to take some combination of rows where the **sum** of the second column is 0. Since you want to minimize the sum of the first column, the correct solution would be `[-10, -7, -5, -3]` whose sum is -25 which is more negative than -12. Is this correct?

Comment: I am incorrect, my apologies. I forgot to specify the constraint that only non-zero values of the second column may be utilized for minimization.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of these clarifications.